# Finding fundamental solution to x^2 - 2y^2 = 1 using a straight line

Tags: linear-algebra, pell-type-equations

I am trying to solve $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$ by introducing Line $L$ with $y = m(x-1)$ as we know that one of the solution's is at $(1;0)$
I get the equation $(1-2m^2)x^2 + 4m^2x - (2m^2+1)$ and then divide it by $(x-1)$. After dividing by $(x-1)$ I'm totally stuck.

Thanks.

P.S. 2nd part of the question tells take $m$ to equal $m = v/u$, where $(u, v)$ is a solution to $u^2 - 2v^2 = 1$ and show that the other point that you found previously has integer coordinates.

Comment: Are you only looking for solutions on the line $L$?

Comment: Yes. Only on the line.

Comment: But, is there a theorem or sth that it doesn't have other solutions? Or it may have?

Comment: There's also another part of the question I just found which I don't really get. It says Suppose that you take m to equal m = v/u, where (u, v) is a solution to u^2 - 2v^2 = 1. Show that the other point that you found previously has integer coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange it as
$$x^2-1=2y^2\,.$$
Then, if you want solutions of the form $y=m(x-1)$, this becomes
$$(x-1)(x+1)=2m^2(x-1)^2$$
Then divide by $x-1$ and rearrange:
$$1+2m^2=(2m^2-1)x$$
That is,
$$x=\frac{2m^2+1}{2m^2-1}=1+\frac2{2m^2-1}\,.$$
Now if you want *integer* solutions, there is not too many options for $m$:
$$m=-1,0,1$$
Each one gives you a solution on the line.

Comment: That explains a lot now. But there's also another part of the question I just found which I don't really get. It says Suppose that you take m to equal m = v/u, where (u, v) is a solution to u^2 - 2v^2 =
1. Show that the other point that you found previously has integer coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The product of the roots of the quadratic is $\frac{2m^2+1}{2m^2-1}$. Since one of the roots is $1$, the other is $\frac{2m^2+1}{2m^2-1}$.

Now we compute $y$ from $y=m(x-1)$. That gives $y=\frac{2m}{2m^2-1}$.  We have obtained a parametric solution of the original equation.  And as $m$ ranges over all *rationals*, the parametric solution ranges over all rational solutions other than $(1,0)$.